# Capacitance of octant of a sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

What's the capacitance of octant of a sphere if the capacitance of sphere is C? I think that some combination of octants should make the capacitance of the whole. But what combination will it be exactly? Four parallel wires with 2 octants in series?